# Fails to resolve dependency for a sub-module with spring boot plugin

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I use gradle, and has a module/project that has spring boot plugin applied. Lets Say in a project `sub-module`, I have `apply plugin: "spring-boot"`.

Now from a another module/project I am adding a testCompile dependency to the sub-module. Say from another project `main-module`, I have added the below dependency

```
dependencies {
   testCompile project(":sub-module")
}
```

But when I test compile `main-module`, I get the below error,

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':main-module:testCompile'.
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging//spring-boot-starter-logging-.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging//spring-boot-starter-logging-.jar
  Required by:
      com.xx.xx-main-module:1.0-SNAPSHOT > com.xx.xx:sub-module:1.0-SNAPSHOT
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-solr:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-solr//spring-boot-starter-data-solr-.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-solr//spring-boot-starter-data-solr-.jar
  Required by:
      com.xx.xx:main-module:1.0-SNAPSHOT > com.xx.xx:sub-module:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

The above error implies that I need to apply spring-boot in `main-module` as well and have all the buildScript dependencies to spring repos in the main-module build.gradle.

Just seems wrong that `main-module` has to declare plugins and dependencies that it is least bothered about.

Gradle version : 2.10
Spring-boot version : 1.3.2.RELEASE

Comment: Made some edits to the error messages.